# doesn't set _locale FOSUserBundle symfony 3

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.3

I'm using symfony 3 And use FOSUserBundle.

I Want to have automatically redirect when I don't have _locale in url

for example

http://127.0.0.1:8000/

it's 404

http://127.0.0.1:8000/en it's ok

I'd like to have en like default.

my conf.yml

```
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi: ~
    translator: ~ #default
    secret: '%secret%'
```

myroutes:

```
  fos_user_security_login             GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/login
  fos_user_security_check             POST       ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/login_check
  fos_user_security_logout            GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/logout
  fos_user_profile_show               GET        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/profile/
  fos_user_profile_edit               GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/profile/edit
  fos_user_registration_register      GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/register/
  fos_user_registration_check_email   GET        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/register/check-email
  fos_user_registration_confirm       GET        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/register/confirm/{token}
  fos_user_registration_confirmed     GET        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/register/confirmed
  fos_user_resetting_request          GET        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/resetting/request
  fos_user_resetting_send_email       POST       ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/resetting/send-email
  fos_user_resetting_check_email      GET        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/resetting/check-email
  fos_user_resetting_reset            GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/resetting/reset/{token}
  fos_user_change_password            GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/profile/change-password
```

homepage                            ANY        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/

Even when I do logout with

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}">Logout</a>
```

I have an error because my redirect is on /login

my security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

            logout:
                path: fos_user_security_logout
                target: /
            anonymous:    true
            remember_me:
                secret: '%secret%'

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/[a-z]+/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/[a-z]+/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/[a-z]+/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the beginning of your routing configuration (`/app/config/routing.yml`):

```
# Redirecting the root ("/" to the homepage)
root:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
        route: homepage
        permanent: true
```

Then, in your homepage controller, make sure your route is including `_locale` parameter:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Controller/Homepage/HomepageController.php

namespace AppBundle\Controller\Homepage;

class HomepageController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/{_locale}",
     *          name="homepage",
     *          requirements={
     *              "_locale": "%app.locales%"
     *          }
     * )
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function homepageAction(Request $request)
    {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

About `FOSUserBundle`, you should add a prefix in the routing configuration. I assume you've already overriden `FOSUserBundle` by your own `UserBundle`, this will be in the file `/src/UserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.yml`. Then you can choose if you use the default `FOSUserBundle` routing, or your custom routing.

```
# Security
fos_user_security:

    # FOSUserBundle default security routes
    #resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

    # UserBundle custom security routes
    resource: "@UserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.yml"

    prefix: /{_locale}
    requirements:
        _locale: '%app.locales%'

# Profile
fos_user_profile:

    # FOSUserBundle default profile routes
    #resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"

    # UserBundle custom profile routes
    resource: "@UserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.yml"

    prefix: /{_locale}/profile
    requirements:
        _locale: '%app.locales%'

# Registration
fos_user_register:

    # FOSUserBundle default registration routes
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"

    # UserBundle custom registration routes
    #resource: "@UserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.yml"

    prefix: /{_locale}/register
    requirements:
        _locale: '%app.locales%'

# Resetting Password
fos_user_resetting:

    # FOSUserBundle default resetting routes
    #resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"

    # UserBundle custom resetting routes
    resource: "@UserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.yml"

    prefix: /{_locale}/resetting
    requirements:
        _locale: '%app.locales%'
```

And of course, I forgot to mention that you need to specify the parameter `app.locales` in your configuration (`/app/config/config.yml`):

```
parameters:
    # Locale authorized for routing
    app.locales : en|fr|es
```